# HorizontalFieldManager animation in Blackberry

Tags: animation, blackberry, java-me

Can I animate the HorizontalFieldManager in Blackberry?
I have a button in the bottom bar of the screen, and there is an array of images which display in a horizontal layout above the button.

When I click on the button, there should be a slide-in slide-out effect and the images appear one after the other.

Can anyone suggest me any tutorial or link for this?

Comment: Check eye lid manager supported in os 5 or above.

Comment: yeah but it is only for top and bottom layouts. What if I want to add a layout in the center?

Comment: I'm afraid animations in BB are only available in the API on a per screen basis. There's nothing to animate managers or fields, but of course you can DIY.

Answer (score 1):

I think the working approach will be in implementing your own custom bitmap field and placing it above the button, you want to press. When button is pressed, then intercept this event and update contents of your custom bitmap field.

[Here is an example, how to create a custom field with RIM SDK](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_custom_field_508117_11.jsp).